How to enable sorting to an amplify appsync auto-generated query
I have model ChatRoom below created using AppSync-Amplify. Amplify auto-generates list queries for this model such as listChatRooms. Is there a way I could sort listChatRooms based on its updatedAt values (a field that is also auto-generated by amplify)?
type ChatRoom 
    @model 
  @auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner },
    { allow: owner, ownerField: "ids", operations: [read] },
    { allow: private, provider: iam, operations: [create, update, delete] } 
  ])
{
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  ids: [String] 
  Messages: [Message] @hasMany(indexName: "byChatRoom", fields: ["id"])
  Users: [User] @manyToMany(relationName: "UserChatRoom") 
  LastMessage: Message @hasOne
  matchedInterests: [String] 
}

